# Google compute engine list / instances delete fails regexp

Tags: image, list, google-compute-engine, instances, gcloud

I created a private image of a Google compute engine persistent disk, called primecoin01.
Later on, I'm trying to create a new image.  It fails by saying the regexp is invalid both in listing the images and during gcloud.compute.instances.delete - the 1st step in using my persistent disk to create an image.  It let me create the image name and now I'm unable to use the commands gcloud compute images list or gcloud compute instances delete instance-0  --keep-disks boot.  I do not know a way to delete this image from my list.
primecoin01 certainly meets the regular expression criteria, and I have no clue why it named the image apparently ``primecoin01  All help greatly appreciated.

Details below:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute images list
NAME                                PROJECT           ALIAS              DEPRECATED STATUS
centos-6-v20141021                  centos-cloud      centos-6                      READY
centos-7-v20141021                  centos-cloud      centos-7                      READY
coreos-alpha-494-0-0-v20141108      coreos-cloud                                    READY
coreos-beta-444-5-0-v20141016       coreos-cloud                                    READY
coreos-stable-444-5-0-v20141016     coreos-cloud      coreos                        READY
backports-debian-7-wheezy-v20141021 debian-cloud      debian-7-backports            READY
debian-7-wheezy-v20141021           debian-cloud      debian-7                      READY
container-vm-v20141016              google-containers container-vm                  READY
opensuse-13-1-v20141102             opensuse-cloud    opensuse-13                   READY
rhel-6-v20141021                    rhel-cloud        rhel-6                        READY
rhel-7-v20141021                    rhel-cloud        rhel-7                        READY
sles-11-sp3-v20140930               suse-cloud        sles-11                       READY
sles-11-sp3-v20141105               suse-cloud        sles-11                       READY
sles-12-v20141023                   suse-cloud                                      READY
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Invalid value '``primecoin01'. Values must match the following regular expression:     '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z]
(?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute instances delete instance-0  --keep-disks boot
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete) Unable to fetch a list of zones. Specifying  [--zone] may fix this issue:
 - Invalid value '``primecoin01'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z]  (?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute instances delete instance-0  --keep-disks boot --zone us-central1-b
The following instances will be deleted. Attached disks configured to
be auto-deleted will be deleted unless they are attached to any other
instances. Deleting a disk is irreversible and any data on the disk
will be lost.
 - [instance-0] in [us-central1-b]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete) Failed to fetch some instances:
 - Invalid value '``primecoin01'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z]
(?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the instance and the image from the Developers Console? Also, the name appears like <``primecoin01>, this might be causing the error

Comment: A disk called primecoin01 is attached to an instance called instance-0 in my Developers Console.  It is the only disk that I spent about 2 hours on that actually works.  Any attempt to snapshot it, clone it, etc. fail due to the message listed above.  Not willing to erase all of my work on the only working disk, that is not named what is shown above.  I do not know if they escape the word prime or something similar.  I only know the failure listed as told above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a validation error when creating the disk and the name is not correct. Are you still having the same issue? 
A way to create a 'snapshot' of your disk will be to use the dd Linux command to burn your image and then tar the file to [create an image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#creating_an_image_from_a_tar_file) from this file.